# Redireccion 301 con htaccess duda

Tags: .htaccess

Es posible hacer la siguiente redirección a traves de htaccess con operadores logicos?

dominio1/loquesea/archivo.php --> dominio2/loquesea/archivo.php

¿siendo una regla generica? es decir por ejemplo para redireccionar todas las imagenes de una carpeta de un servidor a otro manteniendo la ruta relativa?

Mas que con imagenes quiero hacerlo con metodos de una API quiero que cuando es llame a un metodo de la API en un servidor, responda el otro

Comment: podrias hacerlo :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255967/htaccess-redirect-all-requests-to-different-domain

Comment: He seguido las reglas que pone aqui sustituyendo por mi nombre de dominio pero no funcionan siempre me redirigen al raiz y no al metodo de la API que le pido

Answer (score -1):

Podrías agregar esto en tu archivos de reglas htaccess del servidor 1:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ http://otroservidor.com/$1/$2 [NC,R=302,L]
```

Puedes cambiarlo a 301. Si ya esta seguro.

Espero haberte apoyado.

Saludos

Comment: Esto no te sirvió? ._.